# Connecting NodeJS with React to create notification system

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Good afternoon, I'm pretty new to React since mostly was doing NodeJS stuff before and I come with a problem that I currently don't know how to connect my backend with frontend parts together.

GOAL: I wan't to create a price alert which is going to send me a email notification.
I have a Dropdown Where I can write a `Symbol Name` and `Price` and `Set` it up. I wan't to create an alert when Price is getting bigger than writed in DropDown. F

Example: I Open a DropDown - write `ADABTC` in first textarea `500` click `Set` button and

I already have email notification script ready I was using - [NodeMailer Package](https://nodemailer.com/about/)

I'm also using [Binance API](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md) to receive the `Price`

Here is my **ReactJS Code** part.(**Event.jsx**)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const assets = [
  "ADABTC",
  "AIONBTC",
  "ALGOBTC",
  "ARDRBTC",
  "KAVABTC",
  "ETHBTC",
  "ETCBTC"
];

export default function App() {
  const [queries, setQueries] = useState([]);
  const [symbol, setSymbol] = useState("");
  const [price, setPrice] = useState("");
  const [dropdown, setDropdown] = useState([]);

  const onChangeSymbol = e => {
    setSymbol(e.target.value);
  };

  const onChangePrice = e => {
    setPrice(e.target.value);
  };

  var today = new Date();
  var date =
    today.getFullYear() + "-" + (today.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + today.getDate();
  var time =
    today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
  var dateTime = date + " " + time;

  const onClick = () => {
    if (symbol !== "" && price !== "") {
      setQueries(queries => {
        return [
          ...queries,
          `${symbol}` + " " + `${price}` + " " + "(" + dateTime+")"
        ];
      });
      setSymbol("");
      setPrice("");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (symbol !== "" && symbol !== assets.find(rec => rec === symbol)) {
      setDropdown(assets.filter(rec => rec.indexOf(symbol) > -1));
    } else {
      setDropdown([]);
    }
  }, [symbol]);

  return (
    <div id="DropDownArea" className="DropDownField">
      <div id="PriceAlertHistory">
        <h6>Price Alert History</h6>
      </div>
      <ul>
        {queries.map(query => (
          <li>{query}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Symbol"
        value={symbol}
        onChange={onChangeSymbol}
      />
      <input
        type="number"
        placeholder="Price"
        value={price}
        onChange={onChangePrice}
      />
      <button type="submit" onClick={onClick}>
        Set
      </button>
      <ul>
        {dropdown.length !== 0
          ? dropdown.map(asset => {
              return (
                <li
                  onClick={() => {
                    setSymbol(asset);
                    setDropdown([]);
                  }}
                >
                  {asset}
                </li>
              );
            })
          : false}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is my **NodeJS Code** which is receiving data from Binance API.(**Databases.js**)

```
const getBTCData = async symbol => {
    let data = await fetch(`https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=${symbol}&interval=1d&limit=1`).then(res => res.json());
    const btcusdtdata = data.map(d => {
        return {
            Open: parseFloat(d[1]),
        }
    });
    let volume = await fetch(`https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr?symbol=${symbol}`).then(res => res.json());
    const volumedata = data.map(d => {
        return {
            Volume: parseFloat(volume.quoteVolume)
        }
    });
    console.log(btcusdtdata[0]);
};
```

This is **NodeMailer** script(**Email.js**)

```
require('dotenv').config()
"use strict"; // This is ES6 specific. Help's to run code faster(IMPORTANT FOR NOTIFICATION SYSTEM)
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

async function main() {

    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "smtp.gmail.com",
        port: 465,
        secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
        auth: {
            user: process.env.DB_USER, // OUR ALARM EMAIL
            pass: process.env.DB_PASS, // OUR ALARM PASSWORD
        },
    });

    let info = await transporter.sendMail({
        from: process.env.DB_USER, // sender address
        to: process.env.DB_RECEIVER, // list of receivers
        subject: `Asset is UP`, // Subject line
        text: "ASSET IS UP", // plain text body
    });
    console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Hey, we can have a chat somewhere about your question

Comment: @AlexAV-dev hey! https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218807/room-for-hexycode-and-alexav-dev chat link